# I am trying to write a code for fahrenheit to celcius using functions in c

Tags: c

I am trying to use a function to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius. I wish to know where I made a mistake.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void degrees_Fto_C(float f){
    float c;
    c=(5/9)*(f–(32));
    printf("%f",c);
}

int main(){
    float temp;
    printf("Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit: \n");
    scanf("%f",&temp);
    degrees_Fto_C(temp);
    return 0;
}
```

The error message is:

```
C:\Users\Pranavs\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp  In function 'void degrees_Fto_C(float)':
C:\Users\Pranavs\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp  [Error] 'f' cannot be used as a function
```

Comment: `5/9` is integer math. You want one side of that to a float or double.`(5.0f/9)`

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong character after the f in line 4. `c=(5/9)*(f–(32))` needs to be `c=(5.0/9) * (f-(32))`.  Your minus sign is a unicode character, and you need ASCII. If you backspace it and replace it with a normal minus sign, it will compile.

Also, you're doing integer arithmetic, and you'll always get zero.  It will work better if you add a decimal point after the 5 or the 9.

Here's a working version of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void degrees_Fto_C(float f) {
    float c;
    c = (5.0 / 9) * (f - (32));
    printf("%f", c);
}
int main() {
    float temp;
    printf("Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit: \n");
    scanf("%f", &temp);
    degrees_Fto_C(temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside, Why use `float c;` rather than `double c;`?  `(5.0 / 9) * (f - (32))` is `double` math and `printf("%f", c);` promotes `c` to `double`.